# How to write in ANTLR3 the equivalent of " exp ( PLUS^ exp)* " when the operator is a whitespace (space between two expressions)

Tags: antlr, antlr3

To Parse Excel formulas, I need a rule for range intersection.
For example:

```
= SUM(A1:C4 B2:D3)`
```

is equivalent in Excel to:

```
= SUM(B2:C3)
```

(the intersection of the 2 areas)

The rule is:

```
range ( range )*
```

but I can't find a way to write the tree part, because I only found how to do it with an actual lexer token with the `^` operator, like for an addition, it would be:

```
range (PLUS^ range )*
```

but here the INTERSECT token is an arbitrary one, because elsewhere the space character is only whitespace.

I think I need to use the `->` tree syntax but I can't found in the ANTLR3 guide or on the web how to write the equivalent of `range (PLUS^ range )*` with the `->` syntax.
Here is my current attempt:

```
range ( range {hasIntersect=true})* 
-> {hasIntersect}? ^(INTERSECT range*)
-> range
```

I works for `A1:C4 B2:D3` but for `A1:C4 B2:D3 B1:B6` it produces one INTERSECT tree with 3 children instead of 2 INTERSECT trees with 2 children each, like it would for the other operation.

And I need the tree to only have 2 children of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky as it effectively builds a recursive structure, but it can be done even in one rule:

```
my_rule:
    (
        r1=range
        -> $r1
    )
    (   (
            r2=range
            -> ^(INTERSECT $my_rule $r2)
        )
    )*
```

The crucial part here is the `$rule` reference (name same as the rule name), which will contain the AST as produced so far by the rewrite rules.

Comment: Perfect. All unit tests now pass :)
Thanks from Paris, I would not have thought that you can use the rule name as a tree attribute...